# Bash script to read a text file and then output each line into variables

Tags: arrays, bash, multidimensional-array, sed

I have a file called test that contains an unkown number of lines:

```
<label>blogname</label><type>string</type>
<label>blog description</label><type>text</type>
```

I would like to use SED or AWK to read that file and store each label and each type into a separate variable or even better into an array.

this example would output the content of label in a file:

```
awk -vRS="</variable>" '/<variable>/{gsub(/.*<variable>/,"");print}' test >result
```

But I need to the contents of each line and separate them by the content of each tag to give me something like this:

```
label="blogname"
type="string"
```

I would then need to process the array with a do while script.

I have been searching for a solution to this for hours but had no luck.

Comment: You could probably write an `awk` script to output a line with the label followed by a line with the type and use `read` in a `while` loop in bash to put the values into an array. Look up `read` and bash arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should never really be used. It solves the problem, but a bash script is not really what you want to use for such a task.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
    label=`echo $line | sed -n 's|^.*<label>\(.*\)</label>.*$|\1|p'`
    type=`echo $line | sed -n 's|^.*<type>\(.*\)</type>.*$|\1|p'`
    echo "label:" $label
    echo "type:" $type
    echo
done
```

Edit: Another version inspired by the comment by perelman

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -n 's|^<label>\(.*\)</label><type>\(.*\)</type>.*$|\1\n\2|p' | while read label; do
    read type
    echo "label:" $label
    echo "type:" $type
    echo
done
```

Comment: The solution provided was great but I tried to add a third variable but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/<\([^>]*\)>\([^<]*\)<\/\1>/&\n/g' file |
sed '/^\s*$/d;s/<\([^>]*\)>\([^<]*\)<\/\1>/\1="\2"/'
label="blogname"
type="string"
label="blog description"
type="text"
```